# folium draw circle not drawing

Tags: python, jupyter, folium

I'm trying to draw some circles to outline koala sightings around Brisbane Aus. When I try and run it in jupyter, it draws the map and if I replace the `coordinate[["decimalLatitude"],coordinate["decimalLongitude"]]` with actual values, it displays, but otherwise it doesn't. Here's my code and a sample pic of the data.

```
import folium

map_of_koala_sightings = folium.Map(
    location =[-27.470125,153.021072],
    zoom_start=13, tiles='Stamen Terrain'
)


for coordinate in koala_df:
    try:
        folium.Circle(
        radius=300,
        location = coordinate[["decimalLatitude"],coordinate["decimalLongitude"]],
        color='#3388ff',
            fill=True).add_to(map_of_koala_sightings)
    except:
        pass
map_of_koala_sightings
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Ejv.png)

Comment: The [] are in the wrong place. Try `location = [coordinate["decimalLatitude"],coordinate["decimalLongitude"]],`

Comment: @DS_London hmmm didnt seem to work, i've changed the map draw location so its now the first element coordinates and it moves to the first coordinates, but still fails to draw

Comment: Add a `print(koala_df.head())` line to check the dataframe has loaded correctly first (as you don’t show us how you load the data). Then iterate using `for idx,coordinate in koala_df.iterrows():` instead. As an aside probably drop the try/except structure for now as it is preventing you from seeing where and how things are going wrong.

Comment: @DS_London ive removed the try and am getting this error `string indices must be integers` , all the data loads in correctly, but I assume that there is something making the column read as string instead of int

Comment: I've added some code as an answer. I don't know how you have constructed your `koala_df` DataFrame, so you may have a different format. As above, please add `print(koala_df.head())` in your code and add the output to your question, as that seems to be the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (with a subset of coordinates).

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

koala_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['decimalLatitude','decimalLongitude'],
                        data = [[-26.770484,152.838467],
                                [-28.103458,153.375882],
                                [-26.4,146.25]])

print(koala_df.head())


map_of_koala_sightings = folium.Map(
    location =[-27.470125,153.021072],
    zoom_start=5, tiles='Stamen Terrain'
)


for idx,coordinate in koala_df.iterrows():
    folium.Circle(radius=300,
                  location = [coordinate['decimalLatitude'],coordinate['decimalLongitude']],
                  color='#3388ff',
                  fill=True).add_to(map_of_koala_sightings)

#map_of_koala_sightings

#For saving to html file
map_of_koala_sightings.save('koalas.html')
```

Output:

```
   decimalLatitude  decimalLongitude
0       -26.770484        152.838467
1       -28.103458        153.375882
2       -26.400000        146.250000
```

and 'koalas.html' contains:

[image]

Comment: Worked for me when I replaced my `for coordinate in koala_df:
    try:
        folium.Circle(
        radius=300,
        location = coordinate[["decimalLatitude"],coordinate["decimalLongitude"]],
        color='#3388ff',
            fill=True).add_to(map_of_koala_sightings)` with the given answer's part

Comment: @NickSchofield Glad to hear it. Nice to help on code highlighting two endangered bear species!